# How to import data from XLSX file hosted on SharePoint Online (not lists)?

Tags: excel, office365, sharepoint-online

**TL;DR: I'm looking for the equivalent of Excel 2019's `Get Data > From File > From Workbook` functionality, but where "workbook" is hosted on SharePoint online.**

This seems so simple but yet after hours of searching I cannot find anything remotely close.  This question does not relate to SharePoint Lists (or file lists).  I am literally needing to read data from one online spreadsheet and place into another.

I have three Excel documents hosted on SharePoint Online:

1. Revenue Tracker.xlsx
2. Cost Tracker.xlsx
3. Time Tracker.xlsx

I need to create a fourth file, that analyses the data from the above files, for example to cross-reference revenue against hours.

Based on solutions online, I've tried the following within Excel:

**Data > Get Data > From File > From SharePoint Folder**

That provided a list of documents located in that SharePoint folder.

**Data > Get Data > From Online Services > From SharePoint Online List**

Not what I'm looking for.

**Create share link in Revenue Tracker.xlsx, then in new file Get Data > From Other Sources > From Web > Paste Url**

*Error: Access to the resource is forbidden.* Even though I am correctly logged into Excel using my work SharePoint credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can import data from Excel stored in SharePoint to Excel desktop by using `Get Data > Web` option.

Paste the path to the Excel file in the the URL bar that appears.

EXAMPLE:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Import-Data-from-an-Excel-sheet-in-SharePoint/td-p/47223

Comment: Is Power BI Desktop a commercial product?  I only have Power BI which looks like a report "viewer".  I only have an Office365 essentials license.

Comment: Power BI is now part of Excel. Microsoft bought it. When you use that IMPORT feature you are using PowerBI. That's it.

Comment: I pasted in the URL, but I get an "access forbidden" message.  Maybe its the wrong URL (as there's the URL in the browser, the URL in the browser editor, the read-only URL, and the edit URL, and whatever else I'm missing...)

Comment: You need to have an active login open in Internet Explorer while you are doing this. That's the only way to have your login credentials cached at an OS level. How would Excel log in to SharePoint?

Comment: Still getting the error despite an open session in IE11.  Doesn't Excel retain my Office365 credentials that I use to access SharePoint Online, and that's how I can open documents straight from there?